# How do I spoof the current date when running a bash script?

Tags: bash, date

I have an interactive bash script that I run approximately daily, sometimes multiple times per day as needed. The script uses `find` to look for log files that are guaranteed to have dates in the filenames,<sup>1</sup> then reacts accordingly.

For example:

- if today is Monday–Thursday, `find . -regex ".*<date range X>.log" -exec <mid-week-script> {} \+`
- if today is Friday, `find . -regex ".*<date range Y>.log" -exec <friday-script> {} \+`
- if today is the last Friday of the month, `find . -regex ".*<date range Z>.log" -exec <end-of-month-script> {} \+`.

How can I simulate a different date while I run this script to test its behavior on different dates? I'd rather not mess with the system clock (and may not even have the right permissions), and I don't want to simulate it by changing the commands in the script with  `date -d` because the `date` commands are part of what I'm trying to test. The `<date range>`s in the find commands are built in part by the results of `date`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Dates in the file name are guaranteed, but the files' timestamps are not known, so `-atime` and `-mtime` won't work for my use case.

Comment: Have you ... reinvented cron?

Comment: There are various tools written in C you can install as `LD_PRELOAD`-able libraries to spoof the clock, but those tools aren't part of bash and I'm not sure they're on-topic here (we don't do tool/library recommendation requests). Causing `date` (an external command provided by your operating system and not included with the shell) to spoof arbitrary timestamps isn't something bash itself comes with facilities to do.

Comment: That said, unless you need to support ancient versions of bash (like the one MacOS ships with), I don't recommend using the `date` command at all. Bash has its own built-in primitives for checking the current time, formatting epoch time into desired formats, &c with `printf '%(...)T'` which are vastly more efficient.

Comment: ...and if you're using the `printf` approach to get the current day-of-week, there _are_ good ways to spoof it that don't require tools that aren't included in bash itself. But I'd need to see a [mre] mocking up the thing you're trying to accomplish to be able to write an example of how that would look in practice.

Comment: You could mock date with `date(){ echo 'something else'; }` then `unset -f date`

Comment: `date` displays the system date/time so you either need to modify the system date/time (perhaps in a virtual machine or (docker) container), or implement a custom version of `date` (and any other command you are looking to test that accesses the system date/time); this could be as 'simple' as custom functions (or shell scripts) that reference a user-defined offset to calculate the simulated time (ie, current time + offset); functions may be preferable since they are accessed before `bash` builtins and system binaries

Comment: I think Cole's suggestion to "shadow" /bin/date with a function (I suppose it would work as advertised) is the best.

Comment: regardling the latest update of the question ... using `find` to check for specific `-atime/-mtime` settings ... instead of spoofing the system date/time you could spoof the `-a/-m` attributes of some test files; see `touch -a/-m`

Answer (score 0):

I think, as I said in comments, that Cole's suggestion to shadow /bin/date with a function like `date(){ echo 'something else'; }` is the best solution.

Another approach would be to **separate concerns:** Let the script that does the actual work *process* dates it gets from elsewhere, for example by reading a string from the standard input. That's a bit like separating input routines from the actual processing. This strategy makes the processing more flexible because it can be plugged in to different processing chains. Even if it is unlikely that you'll ever want to use anything else than the system date this strategy *does* facilitate testing, a bit like the main advantage of injection over inheritance may be easier testability.

In this case, a trivial wrapper script would normally call `/bin/date` or equivalent and feed its output to the script, but for testing purposes one could echo something else.